# Issue using parent variables in extended class

Tags: php

I need to pass variables found in parent class to the extended class, but all i get is a notice that the variables are undefined.

I am not sure what is wrong and my gut says that this is an easy fix, but for some reason i can not see it.

```
<?php
class trackem {

public $hostnm;
public $ip;
public $info;

public function __construct() {
}

public function getNm($hostnm){
    $hostnm = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    //echo $hostnm;
}
public function getIp($ip){
    $ip =  $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
    //echo $ip;
}
public function getBrws($info){
    $info = get_browser(null, true);
    //print_r($info);
}

}

class trackem2file extends trackem{

function wrtInfo(){
    //parent::getBrws($info);
    //parent::getIp($ip);
    //parent::getNm($hostnm);
    parent::__construct();

    $this->hostnm = parent::getNm($hostnm);
    $this->ip = parent::getIp($ip);
    $this->info = parent::getBrws($info);
    $this->filename = 'txt/trackfile.txt';

    $this->fh = fopen($this->filename, 'w');
    fwrite($this->fh, $this->hostnm . '\r\n');
    fwrite($this->fh, $this->ip . '\r\n');
    fwrite($this->fh, $this->info . '\r\n');
    fwrite($this->fh, '--------------------' . '\r\n');
    fclose($this->fh);

}
}

$track2 = new trackem2file();
$track2->wrtInfo();
?>
```

I have tried to find a solution to this for about 2 days now, and I have read some other posts about object inheritance and variables not being loaded to extended classes but was not helpful enough to help me solve this problem. So I now ask for your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use them like this, you missed out the `$this->`:

```
$this->info;
$this->ip;
$this->hostnm;
```

Try this:

```
<?php
class trackem
{
    public $hostnm;
    public $ip;
    public $info;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function getNm()
    {
        $this->hostnm = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    }
    public function getIp()
    {
        $this->ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
    }
    public function getBrws()
    {
        $this->info = get_browser(null, true);
    }

}

class trackem2file extends trackem
{
    function wrtInfo()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->getNm();
        $this->getIp();
        $this->getBrws();
        $filename = 'txt/trackfile.txt';

        $fh = fopen($filename, 'w');
        fwrite($fh, $this->hostnm . '\r\n');
        fwrite($fh, $this->ip . '\r\n');
        fwrite($fh, $this->info . '\r\n');
        fwrite($fh, '--------------------' . '\r\n');
        fclose($fh);

    }
}

$track2 = new trackem2file();
$track2->wrtInfo();
?>
```

Comment: ok this worked partially.. I get no errors anymore.. I still dont get the data found on the variables written in the text file.. any ideas?

Comment: btw i couldnt give u +1 cuz i have 13 rep and i need 15 :P

Comment: try that.. I've changed a couple of things that might make a difference.

Comment: ok this `$this->getNm($this->hostnm);
        $this->getIp($this->ip);
        $this->getBrws($this->info);` made the difference. It is working now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class trackem
{
    public $hostnm
    public $ip;
    public $info;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->hostnm = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $this->ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
        $this->info = get_browser(null, true);
    }
}

class trackem2file extends trackem
{
    public function wrtInfo()
    {
        $data = join(PHP_EOL, [$this->hostnm, $this->ip, $this->info]);
        file_put_contents('txt/trackfile.txt', $data);
    }
}

$track2 = new trackem2file();
$track2->wrtInfo();
```